# Override MimeType for GCDWebserver

Tags: ios, cocoapods, gcdwebserver

I am implementing a simple static webserver using `GCDWebserver`, problem is my jpeg file names do not have a file extension.

This is confusing my clients I see there is a `kGCDWebServerDefaultMimeType` in `GCDWebServerPrivate.h`

```
#define kGCDWebServerDefaultMimeType @"application/octet-stream"
```

What would be the simplest way for me to change this to @"image/jpeg" without changing the library header ? I am using Cocoapods    pod "GCDWebServer", "~> 3.0"

Currently the only code I have is

```
[_webServer addGETHandlerForBasePath:@"/" directoryPath:mediaRoot indexFilename:nil cacheAge:3600 allowRangeRequests:YES];

[_webServer startWithPort:8080 bonjourName:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a high-level wrapper API, you can't customize the `GCDWebServerResponse` instances created internally e.g. to change their `contentType` property.

You would either need to patch the source code to change `kGCDWebServerDefaultMimeType`, or copy-paste the implementation of `-addGETHandlerForBasePath:...` and customize it to your needs by at the minimum changing the `contentType` property of the created `GCDWebServerResponse` instances to `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Could you give me sample code, I am not at all familiar with this library

Comment: Ah, I had missed your were using a high-level wrapper API. I updated my response.